# How do I create URL's in ASP.NET Web Forms without the question mark for querystrings?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, query-string

For example, a traditional URL would look like this:

www.example.com?productID=123

I want it to look like

www.example.com/product/1234

Do I have to use MVC to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried, or what exactly are you having problems with? Are you converting your application from webforms to MVC? Or are you trying to make pretty URLs?

Comment: See [this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx) introducing friendly urls for web forms.

Comment: I'm trying to create more user friendly urls with an existing web forms solution.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to convert entire application to MVC just for the sake of pretty URL.

You can easily achieve it by using [urlrewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/).

Something like this in web.config -

```
<rewriter>
  <rewrite url="~/Product/(\d+)" to="~/default.aspx?productID=$1"/>
</rewriter>
```

*Note: I did not test the above code. I hope you get the idea.*

If your application uses .Net 4.5, you might also want to look at URL Routing of ASP.Net.